# Difference between Jar and War packaging with embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Spring Boot can build executable `.jar` or `.war` files.  Is there any difference between them, besides the file extension?

[The documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) states `You should configure your project to build a jar or war (as appropriate)`.  For a Spring MVC web application, is in inappropriate (for technical reasons) to build an executable `.jar` instead of an executable `.war`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, when you're using an embedded container, you should stick to the defaults and build a jar file.

There are, however, two exceptions to that rule:

1. You want to use JSPs. In that case [you'll need to use war packaging](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations) as Tomcat's JSP support is tightly coupled to the layout of a war file.
2. You want to have the option of also deploying your application to a standalone container or app server.

Comment: Thanks, the JSP support would have been a breaker for me if I'd moved to jar packaging!